# Is $e^e$ irrational?

Tags: number-theory

I was surprised to find out that the following question is open:
Is $e^e$ transcedental?

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel's_conjecture), a positive answer to Schanuel's conjecture implies "yes" to the above question.

My questions:

1) Can we at least prove that $e^e$ is irrational? Or is this also open?

2) Given that $e^e$ is irrational, does it follow that $e^e$ is transcedental?

*Added comment*: For (2) I mean "Does the knowledge that $e^e$ is irrational help with the proof that $e^e$ is transcedental?"

Comment: (2) is certainly not correct.

Comment: I doubt that this can be proved in an easy way.What do you mean in (2)?

Comment: @Paul: What do you mean? It is false? But then the only options for $e^e$ are either rational, or algebraic.

Comment: Good question. Trying for 1, and yes, for 2, not necessarily.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas: I mean "Prove that $e^e$ is transcedental, given the assumption that it is irrational"

Comment: @ABcDexter: I can not understand your answer.

Comment: @Paul: My understanding of (2) was that he was wondering if $e^e$ might have some special property that would allow us to conclude that $e^e$ is transcendental if we knew that $e^e$ was irrational. I don't know the answer, but I very strongly suspect that the answer is NO (i.e. we don't at present know that $e^e$ has any such special property).

Comment: Sidenote: According to [this mathoverflow answer by Matt Papanikolas](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/40145/irrationality-of-pi-e-pi-pi-and-e-pi2/40157#40157), at least one of $e^e$ and $e^{e^2}$ is transcendental.

Comment: Wow Stephan Schanuel was a professor at my university before he passed away

Answer (score 8, accepted):

About (1), it is still unknown whether $e^e$ is irrational or not, according to Wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_number#Open_questions

Even more interesting, according to Gelfond's Theorem, $a^b$ is transcendental (therefore irrational) if $a$ is algebraic (and $\not\in\{0,1\}$) and if $b$ is irrational and algebraic.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GelfondsTheorem.html

This theorem can be used to prove that $e^\pi$ is transcendental and therefore irrational.

Comment: This answers (1).  Let me wait to see if anyone has any ideas about (2) and I will mark the answer correct.

Comment: [Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem): If $a\neq 0$ is algebraic, then $e^a$ is transcendental. It is written in the [list of transcendental numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Numbers_proven_to_be_transcendental).

Comment: How does Gelfond's theorem show $e^\pi$ is irrational?  $\pi$ is certainly not rational, so it doesn't apply in an obvious way.

Comment: @Richard $e^\pi = (-1)^(-i)$